# Percentile of CDF Function

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find the 0.5 (mean) percentile of a CDF function.

$$ F(X) = 1 - e^{-(x/3)^2} $$

In my book's example it says

$$ m = 3[-ln(1-0.5)]^{1/2} = 3\sqrt{ln2}=2.498$$

I am not sure how to get to the above equation even using the definition of a percentile of $$F(x_p) = p $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $50$-th percentile  is the *median*, not the mean. Call it $m$. We want to solve the equation
$$1-e^{-(m/3)^2}=\frac{1}{2},$$
or equivalently 
$$ e^{-(m/3)^2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Take the (natural) logarithm of both sides. We get
$$-\left(\frac{m}{3}\right)^2=\ln(1/2)=-\ln 2.$$
So we are solving $\frac{m^2}{9}=\ln 2$. That gives (since $m$ is positive) $m=3\sqrt{\ln 2}$.